# Getting tensorboard to work with keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensorboard, keras-2

I have an issue that seems to have no straight forward solution in Keras. My server runs on ubuntu 14.04, keras with backend tensorflow.

Here's the issue:

I wanted to use tensorboard to plot the histograms, other training metrics graphs.
I followed the following procedure to do so.

1. I ssh'd to the remote GPU server and started tensorboard with the following command line:

   ```
   tensorboard --port 13987 --log==/home/tharun/Desktop/logs
   ```
2. Further it generated the following output

   ```
   tensorboard --port 13987 --log==/home/tharun/Desktop/logs
   /home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
   from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
   TensorBoard 0.4.0rc3 at http://sidh-pc:13987 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
   ```
3. Then I ssh'd to the remote server to open firefox on that system with the following command line

   ```
   ssh -X tharun@172.26.175.67 firefox -no-remote
   ```
4. In the opened firefox browser http://sidh-pc:13987 was typed in and it opened the tensorboard page. Following information is shown in the window.

   ```
   No dashboards are active for the current data set.

   Probable causes:

   You haven’t written any data to your event files.
   TensorBoard can’t find your event files. 

   If you’re new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add data and set up your event files, check out the README and perhaps the TensorBoard tutorial.

   If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the section of the README devoted to missing data problems and consider filing an issue on GitHub.

   Last reload: Tue Jan 16 2018 18:17:12 GMT+0530 (IST)

   Log directory: =/home/tharun/Desktop/logs
   ```
5. Being confused I checked tensorboard readme.txt at the link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard . Then I typed in the following command in terminal and received the output:

   ```
   (deep-learning) tharun@sidh-pc:~$
   find /home/tharun/Desktop/logs/ | grep tfevents
   /home/tharun/Desktop/logs/events.out.tfevents.1516101897.sidh-pc
   /home/tharun/Desktop/logs/events.out.tfevents.1516101849.sidh-pc
   ```
6. Ran tensorboard in inspector mode to inspect the contents of the event files.

   ```
   (deep-learning) tharun@sidh-pc:~$
   tensorboard --inspect --logdir /home/tharun/Desktop/logs
   /home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
     from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
   ======================================================================
   Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
   ======================================================================

   Found event files in:
   /home/tharun/Desktop/logs

   These tags are in /home/tharun/Desktop/logs:
   audio -
   histograms
      dense_1/bias_0
      dense_1/bias_0_grad
      dense_1/kernel_0
      dense_1/kernel_0_grad
      dense_1_out
      dense_2/bias_0
      dense_2/bias_0_grad
      dense_2/kernel_0
      dense_2/kernel_0_grad
      dense_2_out
      dense_3/bias_0
      dense_3/bias_0_grad
      dense_3/kernel_0
      dense_3/kernel_0_grad
      dense_3_out
   images -
   scalars
      acc
      loss
      val_acc
      val_loss
   tensor -
   ======================================================================

   Event statistics for /home/tharun/Desktop/logs:
   audio -
   graph
      first_step           0
      last_step            0
      max_step             0
      min_step             0
      num_steps            1
      outoforder_steps     []
   histograms
      first_step           0
      last_step            149
      max_step             149
      min_step             0
      num_steps            150
      outoforder_steps     []
   images -
   scalars
      first_step           0
      last_step            149
      max_step             149
      min_step             0
      num_steps            150
      outoforder_steps     []
   sessionlog:checkpoint -
   sessionlog:start -
   sessionlog:stop -
   tensor -
   ======================================================================

   (deep-learning) tharun@sidh-pc:~$
   ```

   In the next stage, following script (located at /home/tharun/Desktop/) is run to produce more event files and plot the results in tensorboard

   ```
   from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers import Dense
   import numpy
   from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
   from time import time
   # fix random seed for reproducibility
   numpy.random.seed(7)
   # load pima indians dataset
   dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
   # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
   X = dataset[:,0:8]
   Y = dataset[:,8]
   # create model
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   # Compile model
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
   tensorboard =TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=1, batch_size=1, write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=False, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None)

   # Fit the model
   model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, callbacks=[tensorboard])
   # evaluate the model
   scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
   print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
   ```

   There was no change in the status of tensorboard window. Hence I have restarted the tensorboard server and went through the similar procedure outlined above. But still the tensorboard window in firefox shows the same status log:

   ```
   No dashboards are active for the current data set.

   Probable causes:

       You haven’t written any data to your event files.
       TensorBoard can’t find your event files. 

   If you’re new to using TensorBoard, and want to find out how to add data and set up your event files, check out the README and perhaps the TensorBoard tutorial.

   If you think TensorBoard is configured properly, please see the section of the README devoted to missing data problems and consider filing an issue on GitHub.

   Last reload: Tue Jan 16 2018 18:46:45 GMT+0530 (IST)

   Log directory: =/home/tharun/Desktop/logs
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in terminal did the  trick!! Currently situated in /home/tharun/Desktop/ directory

```
tensorboard --logdir=./
/home/tharun/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
TensorBoard 0.4.0rc3 at http://sidh-pc:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
W0117 22:24:07.582409 Reloader plugin_event_accumulator.py:303] Found more than one graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def, as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the newest event.
W0117 22:24:42.635272 Reloader plugin_event_accumulator.py:311] Found more than one metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest event.
```